# Derivative of parametric function

Tags: derivatives

could you please help me with this question. I get $\dfrac {da}{dx}$ as 1 and after separating  $\dfrac {dy}{dz}$ into  $\dfrac {dy}{da}$ * $\dfrac {da}{dz}$ i get $(1-a)  e^z$ but there is no such choice in answers. Am i doing it right? Here is question:
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOi1n.jpg)

Comment: I did it like you and I don't see the answer either when replacing $(1-a)$ and $e^z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. Maybe we are overlooking a detail

Comment: I get $dy/dz=e^z-2e^{2z}$=$a-2a^2$=$x+1-2(x+1)^2$=etc